# Are questions about film theory on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I have a specific question in mind regarding Laura Mulveys theory of Male Gaze and Noel Carrols later criticism of it (Where there serious replies to Carrol? What does remain of Mulveys Male Gaze if we remove the psychoanalytic underpinings?). I'd need to put some more thoughts into to make it a specific answerable question and don't know if it's worth the bother. It appears there are few or no questions about film theory (then again, I, not beeing a film theory person, might have found them).

**Edit to add:** The question I'm maybe about to ask is **not** applying a theory to a specific movie, I'm asking if a certain academic discussion has continued in the last years, with publications etc: Has the theory been "updated" lately (last ten years I think)? So really a question about film theory, not a specific film.

Are questions on film theory on topic and does the sketch above sound like a question that could find an answer here?

Answer (score 5):

Since this is a site concerned with discussing films and TV-shows, their content, composition, themes and impact, the question about on-topicness gets a clear

## Definitely!

It **doesn't have to pertain to a specific film** either. We have a ton of rather general questions about film-techniques as well as more theoretical concepts that don't necessarily discuss just a single specific movie.

But of course you still have to beware the pitfalls of SE with regards to asking **answerable and specific** questions, as you already seem to be considerate of. Asking if there were any academic updates to a specific theory *can* veer into being a little too broad or unspecific, but it might as well work. It really depends on the specific question and sometimes it just comes down to massaging the wording a little to bring it more in line with SE and the kinds of answers you want to encourage.